# CompileXIB com.apple.InterfaceBuilder error 2001 operation couldn’t be completed

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, interface, interface-builder

Compiled my project code and now I receive the following error on all XIB and Storyboard files. Can someone help me solve? All IB files point to the proper deployment target (9.0).

```
CompileXIB App/WelcomeScreenViewController.xib
    cd /Users/jried31/Downloads/zzz/v6/App
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    export XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --module App --output-partial-info-plist /Users/jried31/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-basveboargfgfwdisbiioebismye/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.build/WelcomeScreenViewController-PartialInfo.plist --auto-activate-custom-fonts --target-device iphone --minimum-deployment-target 9.0 --output-format human-readable-text --compile /Users/jried31/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-basveboargfgfwdisbiioebismye/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alure.Me.app/WelcomeScreenViewController.nib /Users/jried31/Downloads/zzz/v6/App/App/WelcomeScreenViewController.xib

/* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
/Users/jried31/Downloads/zzz/v6/App/App/WelcomeScreenViewController.xib: error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.InterfaceBuilder error 2001.)
```

Comment: Sorry having to say that, but: that's an awful read. Try to format this nicely if you really need help

Answer (score 1):

In my case, a merge conflict caused the files to fail to compile, so I just had to open them up in a text editor and resolve the merge.

Comment: Likewise - during a rebase there were some changes that didn't save. Had to view the `storyboard` in `Source Code` and manually resolve conflicts

Answer (score 1):

All the other solution did not work for me. I did not have a merge issue as I got the issue no matter which branch I was using.

In the end I redownloaded Xcode (7.3.1) and now it is working again.

Comment: None of the other answers helped me. The issue occurred even for a clean checkout which compiled fine on other machines, so I very much doubt that it was caused by a bad merge. Reinstalling Xcode (also 7.3.1) and opening the exact same local project solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem:
More Clarification of the issue was that all of the XIB's and Storyboard files would not compile, resulting in the 2001 error.

SOLUTION:
The problem was because the Simulator was based on iOS 9.1 and the build target for both the Podfile and iOS project was 9.0...That inconsistency caused issues. I resolved it by the following:

1. Product -> Clean
2. Product -> (hold down option) Clean build folders
3. Delete Derived Data (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData)
4. Download the 9.0 simulator (if you choose to keep the project at 9.0 settings) resulting in two simulator builds (9.1 and 9.0)
5. Restart XCODE
   --- Just make sure that all of your settings reflect the desired OS version you'd like to go with.